# how to fix 'Type Error:unsuppored operand type(s) for +: 'int ' and 'list' '

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import choice


class RandomWalk():

     """a class generates random datas"""
    def __init__(self, num_points=5000):

        self.num_points = num_points
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]


    def fill_walk(self):
        """caculate all points generated by RandomWalk """
        while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:
            #decide the direction and distance
            x_direction = choice([1,-1])
            x_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            x_step = x_direction * x_distance
            #the same with x
            y_direction = choice([1, -1])
            y_distance = ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            y_step = y_direction * y_distance

            if x_step == 0 and y_step ==0:
                continue

            #caculate next_x and next_y    
            next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
            next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step



            self.x_values.append(next_x)
            self.y_values.append(next_y)


rw_visual.py
```

Here is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random_walk import RandomWalk
#generate a instance named RandomWalk, paint all included points
rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()
plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, s=15)
plt.show()

The result showed that random_walk.py", line 26, in fill_walk
    next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`
```

Comment: This is the first time i use stack overflow. I am sorry that  i put code in rw_visual on wrong place.

Comment: Here is the code  on rw_visual.py

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: from random_walk import RandomWalk

Comment: rw = RandomWalk()

Comment: rw.fill_walk()   plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, s= 15)

Comment: plt.show() .Thank you for  your answer.

Comment: Thankyou.  I have found question in my code. The question is y_distance = ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) , which lacks choice()

Comment: yeah 1 * list returns a list, -1  list returns empty list lol

Comment: If you've found the answer yourself, feel free to answer your own question! That may help anybody else who comes across this question when having the same kind of problem in their own code.

Comment: For future referance, stackoverflow uses markdown syntax for their compose windows. It might be a good idea to brush up on it. Try checking out https://commonmark.org/help/ and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

When you tied to `next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step`, `self.x_values[-1]` was of type `int` and `x_step` was a list.

You left out `choice` so the program was treating `y_distance` as a list. 
In python it's perfectly legal to multiply an `int` by a list, 
so you would end up with `y_step` being `[0*y_distance, 1*y_distance, 2*y_distance, 3*y_distance, 4*y_distance]`. 
So `y_step` was of type list when you went to add it.

```
#decide the direction and distance
x_direction = choice([1,-1])
x_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
x_step = x_direction * x_distance
#the same with y
y_direction = choice([1, -1])
y_distance = ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) # Here you left out choice
y_step = y_direction * y_distance
```

So when the program hit an error, it was trying to

```
next_y = self.y_values[-1] + [0*y_distance, 1*y_distance, 2*y_distance, 3*y_distance, 4*y_distance]
```

Which caused an error because you can't add an integer to a list in Python. This explains your error.

New code for the class:

```py
from random import choice 

class RandomWalk():
    """a class that generates random data"""
    def __init__(self, num_points=5000):
        self.num_points = num_points
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

    def fill_walk(self):
        """calculate all points generated by RandomWalk """
        while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:
            #decide the direction and distance
            x_direction = choice([1,-1])
            x_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            x_step = x_direction * x_distance
            #the same with y
            y_direction = choice([1, -1])
            y_distance = ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            y_step = y_direction * y_distance

            if x_step == 0 and y_step ==0:
                continue

            #calculate next_x and next_y    
            next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
            next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

            self.x_values.append(next_x)
            self.y_values.append(next_y)
```

Also if you want to impress people:

Data can be plural or singular.
The singular of data is datum; always singular.
As in, *"How much data is there? Sir, there is only a datum being returned."*

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_(word))